# Export/Import WordPress metadata from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I imported a WordPress blog that kept all my entries but lost all my Categories, Tags, and custom fields. I have a backup of the MySQL database that contains that info. What kind of MySQL query do I need to fetch/export all that metadata from my backup db, and then import it into my new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would copy the wp_term_relationships, wp_term_taxonomy, wp_terms, and wp_links tables.  Probably wp_postmeta too.  Comments are in the wp_coments and wp_commentmeta tables.  You can just export these tables in their entirety and import the data into your new database.

I think in general, if copying one site to another, you can copy all tables **except** the wp_options table.  This is where the site configuration is stored, and that can cause problems when moved from one site to another.